# Vector reallocation uses copy instead of move constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, move-semantics

Hi I created a class Foo with a noexcept move constructor using gcc 4.7 and set the vector reserve size to 2 so that it would have to reallocate the size when adding the 3rd item. It seems it is calling the copy constructor instead of the move constructor when doing this. Am I missing something here?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
  public:
  Foo(int x) : data_(x)
  {
    std::cout << " constructing " << std::endl;
  }

  ~Foo()
  {
    std::cout << " destructing " << std::endl;
  }

  Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = default;
  Foo& operator=(Foo&&) = default;

   Foo(Foo&& other) noexcept : data_(std::move(other.data_))
   {
    std::cout << " Move constructing " << std::endl;
   }

   Foo(const Foo& other) noexcept :  data_(other.data_)
   {
    std::cout << " Copy constructing " << std::endl;
   }

  private:
  int data_;
};


int main ( int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::vector<Foo> v;
  v.reserve(2);
  v.emplace_back(1);
  std::cout << "Added 1" << std::endl;
  v.emplace_back(2);
  std::cout << "Added 2" << std::endl;
  v.emplace_back(3);
  std::cout << "Added 3" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "v size: " << v.size() << std::endl;
}
```

output:

```
 constructing 
Added 1
 constructing 
Added 2
 constructing 
 Copy constructing 
 Copy constructing 
 destructing 
 destructing 
Added 3
v size: 3
 destructing 
 destructing 
 destructing
```

Comment: My clang build doesn't fire the copy ctor once. get a smarter gcc ?

Comment: It works as expected (that is, `vector` calls the move constructor) with GCC 4.8.1.

Comment: It works fine with [gcc 4.8.1](http://ideone.com/SXoMw2). Could be a bug in 4.7

Comment: hmmm that makes sense I need to upgrade to gcc 4.8.1. I couldn't figure this out forever it was bothering me... Seems like just a bug then. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After tinkering with it a bit with both GCC 4.7 and 4.8, it seems that it is indeed a bug in 4.7, which **only appears when the class' destructor is *not* marked `noexcept`**:

```
struct Foo {
  Foo() {}
  ~Foo() noexcept {}
  Foo(Foo&&) noexcept { std::cout << "move constructor" << std::endl; }
  Foo(const Foo&) noexcept { std::cout << "copy constructor" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
  std::vector<Foo> v;
  v.reserve(2);
  v.emplace_back();
  v.emplace_back();
  v.emplace_back();
}
```

GCC 4.7 displays:

```
move constructor
move constructor
```

If we remove `noexcept` from the destructor:

```
struct Foo {
  Foo() {}
  ~Foo() {}
  Foo(Foo&&) noexcept { std::cout << "move constructor" << std::endl; }
  Foo(const Foo&) noexcept { std::cout << "copy constructor" << std::endl; }
};
```

GCC 4.7 displays:

```
copy constructor
copy constructor
```

GCC 4.8 uses the move constructor in both cases.

Comment: +1 [Found the bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56191). `G++ 4.7 does not apply the rule that destructors are noexcept, so you need to add an explicit noexcept specification on the destructor.  GCC 4.8 correctly makes the destructor noexcept as required by C++11.`