# std::vector seems to prefer copy over move construction when auto-resizing

Tags: c++11, vector, copy-constructor, move-constructor

It seems that when `std::vector` resizes itself (e.g. when inserting a new element and there not being enough room), it uses its elements' copy constructor rather than their move constructor, even if they have both.

- Is that a general rule or do I need to do something to make sure the move ctor is preferred (e.g. mark things as `noexcept`?)
- If this is the general rule - why is that the case?

Notes:

- I'm using GCC 5.4.1 and its associated libstdc++ (but through CUDA 8.0's NVCC) with `--std=c++11`.
- A Possibly related question: [Vector reallocation uses copy instead of move constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18655588/1593077).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enforce move semantics when a vector grows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001823/how-to-enforce-move-semantics-when-a-vector-grows)